# LineChartView chartViewDidEndPanning and chartValueNothingSelected is not getting called while chartValueSelected is being called perfectly

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

Implemented a [ChartView](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) (used Charts library) and got a blocker.

**chartValueSelected** is being called.

However, **chartValueNothingSelected** and **chartViewDidEndPanning** are not getting called.

Note:
**chartView.delegate = self** is called in **viewDidLoad**

Whyy? Anyone experienced this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.